# Can I disable the red overlay box that shows error messages in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the 'Go to Next Problem (Error, ...)' command a lot. The command id is `editor.action.marker.next`. When I do that (and an error exists) vscode jumps to the error and opens a box with the error message below the line that contains the error. Here's a screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVI7.png). Is it possible to disable that error message box, so that it just never opens? (Personally, I would very much prefer to not have that box open. Instead -- if I want to read error messages -- I would open the problem panel at the bottom.)

I tried to google this and searched in the vscode issue tracker without success. But I'm also not even sure what to call this error message box overlay thing when searching for this. So maybe that's where my problem lies. Does this box have a name?

Comment: I don't see a way to disable that info box permanently.  You could make a macro so that whenever you call `editor.action.marker.next` then `closeMarkersNavigation` is immediately called thereafter.  It works but I get the flash of it opening/closing which is a little ugly.  Let me know if you want to see the macro.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, if you have the macro, I'd love to try it out. Thanks for replying!

Comment: There is a closed issue for this feature: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134337

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a macro extension, here [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your `settings.json`:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.gotoNextProblem",
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.marker.next",
        "closeMarkersNavigation"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and some keybinding (in `keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "alt+F8",              // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.gotoNextProblem" },
  }
```

As I mentioned in the comment, it does work but you see a flash of the marker info box open and close immediately so it is not optimal but functional.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this.

(I'm using `vscodevim.vim`, so I can actually do:
`"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [{"before": ["<leader>", "h"], "commands": ["editor.action.marker.nextInFiles", "closeMarkersNavigation"]}]`
in my `settings.json`. Either way, this is great!)